# Class templating std::set key types

Tags: c++, templates, class

I have a class to evaluate set algebra but wish to template it.

At the minute it looks a bit like this

set.h:

```
template<typename T>
  class SetEvaluation
  {
  public:
    SetEvaluation<T>();

    std::set<T>
    evaluate(std::string in_expression);
   }
```

set.cpp

```
template<typename T>
   std::set<T>
   SetEvaluation<T>::evaluate(std::string expression)
   {
     std::set<T> result;
     etc etc...
   }
```

But i'm getting undefined reference errors when compiling.

Is it possible to declare the return type as std::set<T> and then pass std::string as the class template param.

There are no errors in the class but only when I try to instantiate SetEvaluation<std::string>

Can anyone shed light on this problem?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template classes and functions are a bit special and need to be defined in the header file. Then that header file needs to be #included wherever you want to use that template class. If you try to define the template functions in a cpp file the linker and try to call that function from another cpp file, the linker won't be able to resolve the reference because the compiler didn't know what to use for the parameter T when it compiled the file with the template definition in it. The best way to work around this is to 1) define the function in the header file and 2) #include it wherever needed. There's further information about this issue on the [C++ faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.13).

#### Trivia

There is another way to get around this using the Comeau C++ compiler because it supports the 'export' keyword, however that keyword is being deprecated in C++0X.

Answer (score 1):

semicolon ; after

```
template<typename T>
  class SetEvaluation
```

in .h

and define a constructor
at least an empty one or comment it out

```
public:
    SetEvaluation<T>() {}
```

ok, at that case use want to use this from an other file. In this case you have to 
explicit instantiatizate of of this template with this syntax in .cc file:

```
template std::set<std::string> SetEvaluation<std::string>::evaluate(std::string expression);
```

or you have to put the definition to the header file

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.  I have both of those, i just cut down the code to post it here as a sample.

Comment: You have two choice: explicit instantization or put everything to a header. If you want to use with more type the better choice is the header one.

Comment: So my entire class's code has to be in the header file? That's seems a bit daft. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Yes, at that case you can use for every type, but the comipling process will be a lot slower. Using explicit instantization compiling will be faster but you have to instantizate for every type in that cc file.

Answer (score 0):

For a generic solution, define your template methods as inline in the header file, either in the class body or after it:
[For a given compiler system you may be able to do otherwise.]

```
template<typename T>
  class SetEvaluation
  {
  public:
    SetEvaluation<T>() { etc. etc.}

    std::set<T>
    evaluate(const std::string& in_expression);
   };

template<typename T>
   inline std::set<T>
   SetEvaluation<T>::evaluate(const std::string& expression)
   {
     std::set<T> result;
     // etc etc...
   }
```